# Excel Data Connection error on working query - "SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name"

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

Other questions here with this error are in Access, but my query runs fine in Access (2010).

However, when I open a data connection from Excel (2010) to said query, that's when it hits me with "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

As you can see below, first nested SELECT has an impossible `WHERE 1 = 0` is used to define the data types, because of where I have Nulls.

This is what's causing the error. If I remove it, Excel can connect (second set of code).

However, I don't see anything that jumps out to me as a reserved word for Excel.

**Snippet of code causing the problem:**

```
SELECT
 'A' As Emp
, 1 As [aaa]
, 1 As [bbb]
, 'A' As Definition
, 1 As Month
, 1 As Year
, CCur( 1 ) As costA
, 1 As [ccc]
, 1 As [ddd]

FROM [hereA]
WHERE 1 = 0
```

**Shortest version of my query with the error:**

```
SELECT Emp, Sum( [bbb] ) AS theB, Sum( [aaa] ) AS theA, Definition, theMonth, theYear, Sum( costA ) AS costB, Count( [ddd] ) AS [theD], Count( [ccc] ) AS [theC]
FROM (SELECT
 'A' As Emp
, 1 As [aaa]
, 1 As [bbb]
, 'A' As Definition
, 1 As Month
, 1 As Year
, CCur( 1 ) As costA
, 1 As [ccc]
, 1 As [ddd]

FROM [hereA]
WHERE 1 = 0

UNION ALL SELECT

[h_A].[emp_a] AS Emp
, Int( 0 ) AS [aaa]
, Int( 1 ) AS [bbb]
, 'Text1' AS Definition
, theMonth( [h_A].[date1] ) AS [Month]
, theYear( [h_A].[date1] ) AS [Year]
, [h_A].[thisCost] AS costA
, NULL AS [ccc]
, [foo].[d network] AS [ddd]

FROM 
( [hereA] AS [h_A] LEFT JOIN [thereA] 
  ON [h_A].[dcr] = [thereA].[dcr]
)
LEFT JOIN [foo] 
ON [thereA].[s ball*] = [foo].[s ball]

WHERE ( ( [h_A].[date]>=#1/1/2012# ) AND ( Int( [h_A].[indicator] )=1 ) )

)  AS AllowGroupBy
GROUP BY Emp, theMonth, theYear, Definition;
```

Comment: thats to much for me right now. chop the UNION into single queries and try each one by itself. Narrow down the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that changing "Month" and "Year" fixed the issue, although I don't know why it was okay to keep in if I removed the troubling part... Since "Month" and "Year" were still in there.

Answer (score 1):

This is the last part of that query.  It tries to do a union with a `SELECT` of nothing.

```
UNION ALL SELECT 


)  AS AllowGroupBy
GROUP BY Emp, theMonth, theYear, Definition;
```

I'm surprised that even works in Access as you claimed.

Comment: The query itself unions several more tables, with the same formatting, which I deleted for brevity. I missed this line in my deletion. The final union'd table is not followed by a floating 'UNION ALL SELECT'. Thanks.